# Airflow: How to set a dynamic timeout to python sensor

Tags: python, airflow

I have four tasks t1,t2,t3,t4. I want to push a value into xcom in t1 and pull that value from Xcom and use that as timeout in pythonsensor which is t4

Currently the value is hardcoded

```
PythonSensor(
    task_id="poll_status",
    poke_interval=POKE_INTERVAL,
    timeout=180,
    mode=MODE,
    soft_fail=True,
    python_callable=t2       
    )
```

want something like

```
PythonSensor(
    task_id="poll_job_status",
    poke_interval=POKE_INTERVAL,
    timeout=ti.xcom_pull(key="timeout")[0], // value pushed into xcom in t1
    mode=MODE,
    soft_fail=True,
    python_callable=t2       
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to airflow XCOM documentation(https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html), you might wish to use templated result:

```
PythonSensor(
    task_id="poll_job_status",
    poke_interval=POKE_INTERVAL,
    timeout={{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='t1', key='timeout') }}, # value pushed into xcom in t1
    mode=MODE,
    soft_fail=True,
    python_callable=t2       
    )
```

Comment: I tried that, but task_instance is not available to access xcom

Comment: Could you send the error are you getting?

Comment: Compilation error of task_instance not defined